# Get Selected attribute value in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to use Vanilla JS instead of the below jQuery code to get the attribute value of the selection.

`$("#PartnerTypeID").find(':selected').attr('data-id');`

How is this possible?

```js
document.getElementById("PartnerTypeID").addEventListener("change", function() {
  console.log(this.getAttribute("data-id"))
});
```

```html
<select id="PartnerTypeID" name="PartnerTypeID" placeholder="Select...">
  <option value="">Select...</option>
  <option data-id="hospitals" value="1">Hospital</option>
  <option data-id="daycare" value="2">Daycare</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting an event listener on the `select`, which means that `this` refers to that `select` element itself. Which doesn't have the attribute you're looking for, instead you need to get the `option` element that was selected and extract the attribute from there instead.

```js
document.getElementById("PartnerTypeID").addEventListener("change", function() {
  console.log(this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-id"));
});
```

```html
<select id="PartnerTypeID" name="PartnerTypeID" placeholder="Select...">
  <option value="">Select...</option>
  <option data-id="hospitals" value="1">Hospital</option>
  <option data-id="daycare" value="2">Daycare</option>
</select>
```

The [`.options`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/options) property gives you back all the options for the `select` element, and the [`.selectedIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex) property gives you the index of the option currently selected.

Answer (score 0):

```js
PartnerTypeID.onchange = function(){
console.log(this[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-id')) 
}
```

```html
<select id="PartnerTypeID" placeholder="Select...">
  <option value="">Select...</option>
  <option data-id="hospitals" value="1">Hospital</option>
  <option data-id="daycare" value="2">Daycare</option>
</select>
```

This used to work with `this[ this.selectedIndex ].attribute[ 'data-id' ]`, but for some highly ignorant reason - it no longer does!